# Add Caption below algorithm environment

Tags: floats, errors, algorithms, ieeetran

I want to add a caption below algorithm environment that spans over two column page in `\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}`. I use the following:

```
\usepackage[Algorithm,ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{algorithm*}[H]
            This is algorithm
    \end{algorithm*}
\caption{Caption here}
\end{figure*}
```

But I get error `./main.tex:164: LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.` How can I fix that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Id might be easier to help you if you add a MWE, compare https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a caption below an algorithm using the `algorithm2e` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
            This is algorithm
            \caption{Algorithm caption}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're placing a starred float environment (`algorithm*`) inside another starred float environment (`figure*`). You can get away with it by using `figure*` and the `algorithm` with the `[H]`ere float specifier:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
%\usepackage{float} % Already loaded by the algorithm package

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    This is algorithm
  \end{algorithm}
  \caption{Caption here}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Note that your algorithm captions will be printed as a figure caption. However, that might be what you're after.